# How to create multiple catalog's in HSQLDB

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

When using embedded HSQLDB to unit test, it seems the schema and/or the catalog defined in the hibernate entity mapping file can't be handled correctly. The hibernate mapping looks like:

```
<class name="ca.zl.Orders" table="Orders" schema="dbo" catalog="db1">
```

With the property `"hibernate.connection.url"` set to `"jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db1"`, I always got the following errors

> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport: user lacks privilege or object not found: DB1 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport: invalid schema name: DBO
>   This seems caused by HSQLDB by default only has one catalog named "PUBLIC", see document here.

I can't change the hibernate entity mapping, I don't want to use other database engine (I know H2DB can handle this). Can anyone shed a light on how to make HSQLDB work in this unit test context?

Answer (score 0):

The Schema Tooling system in Hibernate ORM does not create the designated database, schema, or respective table spaces.  Its up to the end user to insure those objects exist prior to starting your Hibernate application.

In your case, you're attempting to use a non-default schema called `dbo` and in that case, my suggestion would be to look at using the `import.sql` script feature offered by Hibernate so that you can optionally create if not exists the schema based on your needs at bootstrap.  This should effectively make that schema available in the in-memory database and the remainder of the schema tooling process should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to running your tests, rename the catalog and create the schema:

```
ALTER CATALOG PUBLIC RENAME TO DB1
CREATE SCHEMA DBO
```

Comment: Altering will work for one DAO call but from my Business layer I call different DAO layers. We need different schema at the same time for our integration testing.  It would be better if you provide option to create multiple catalog at the same time.